# Printing Spaces When Reading From a File

Tags: java, string, format, output, printf

I am trying to print the contents of a file that is read using a while loop after the user selects it from the JChooser prompt window.  The file is written in a program and contains an ID, first name, last name, title, and year of birth that is stored in a written data file as "000001BilboBagginsEsq.1020"  I am trying to use another program to choose the data file print the contents to the console such that it displays as:

```
000001          Bilbo              Baggins           Esq.          1020
```

I want to use the printf statement to format the data that is read and stored in the "rec" variable in this manner, but when I pass in the data from the file it seems to ignore the printf format and prints the data like this in the console:

```
1 000001BilboBagginsEsq.1020
```

My program uses the JChooser to pick a file and print its contents using a while loop:

```
while(reader.ready())
                {
                    rec = reader.readLine();
                    line++;                    
                    System.out.printf("\n%4d %-60s ", line, rec);
                }
                    reader.close();
System.out.println("\n\nData file read!");
```

Any help on this would be appreciated.

I tried formatting the rec using printf, expecting the output to display:

```
000001          Bilbo              Baggins           Esq.          1020
```

But instead it still prints:

```
1 000001BilboBagginsEsq.1020
```

Comment: You need to parse the string into separate variables. Ex: `000001BilboBagginsEsq.1020` -> `int id = 1; String firstName = Bilbo; etc...` Is there a consistent format to the lines?

Comment: The data points are in separate variables but they are entered via user input in a separate program in the same project and are stored in a CSV variable as CSVPersonData = ID + firstName + lastName + Title + YOB;  Is this the format you are referring to?

Comment: Still a bit confused. Is `CSVPersonData` a `String`? Why does it not have commas separating the fields? `000001,Bilbo,Baggins,Esq.,1020`? That's what the `C` in `CSV` stands for.

Comment: Sorry I know it is confusing, yes it is a string that contains ID, First Name, Last Name, Title, and YOB.  I realized I did not want the commas in the output but I haven't renamed the variable which I probably should.  I just want them to display with space in between.

Comment: When smash all the data together like that you need some way to unsmash it. There needs to be a pattern. Assuming the first and last fields are always numbers, and the inner 3 fields are capital letters followed by lower case letters, you can use regex: `"(\\d+)([A-Z][a-z]+)([A-Z][a-z]+)([A-Z][a-z.]+)(\\d+)"`

Answer (score 0):

The fields have no delimiter, it appears.

The text `000001BilboBagginsEsq.1020` needs to be delimited somehow.

For the sake of argument, I'm going to presume the first field is a number, and second is a word, starting with an uppercase letter, same with the third and forth field, and the fifth field is a number.

There are a few approaches you can take to accomplish this task.

I recommend using a `Pattern` and `Matcher` to capture the values.
You can then use a basic `class` structure to hold the data for each line.

Consider the following class.

```java
class Entry {
    String fieldA, firstName, secondName, title, fieldE;

    static Entry parse(String string) {
        Entry entry = new Entry();
        String regex = "(\\d+)([A-Z][a-z._]+)([A-Z][a-z._]+)([A-Z][a-z._]+)(\\d+)";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            entry.fieldA = matcher.group(1);
            entry.firstName = matcher.group(2);
            entry.secondName = matcher.group(3);
            entry.title = matcher.group(4);
            entry.fieldE = matcher.group(5);
        }
        return entry;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String string;
        string = "%-15s".formatted(fieldA);
        string += "%-15s".formatted(firstName);
        string += "%-15s".formatted(secondName);
        string += "%-15s".formatted(title);
        string += "%s".formatted(fieldE);
        return string;
    }
}
```

The `parse` method is static, and can be used to return an instance of `Entry`, given the line.
The `toString` method will be used to format the data into a `String`, which we can then print to the standard-out.

You can then use the following method to read a file, line-for-line, and print the data out.

```java
void print(String path) throws IOException {
    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path))) {
        Entry entry;
        String line;
        int count = 0;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            System.out.println(++count + " " + Entry.parse(line));
    }
}
```

Output

```
1 000001         Bilbo          Baggins        Esq.           1020
```